# Ionic 4 - Angular 6 formArrayName not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ionic4

Trying to use `formArrayName` with a list of ionic checkboxes 
This is my control:

```
this.planGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        ...
        PlanEmails: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.formBuilder.group({
                PlanId: '',
                EmailId: ''
            })
        ]),
    });
```

And this is my HTML

```
         <ion-row>
            <ion-col formArrayName="PlanEmails" [sizeXs]="12" [sizeSm]="6" *ngFor="let email of emails">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label>{{email.Title}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox formControlName="EmailId" color="secondary" [value]="email.Id" slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'PlanEmails -> EmailId'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1732)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:1640)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:4454)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:4959)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:4909)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9246)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10514)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11109)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11069)
```

Tried moving formArrayName to `ion-row` and to `ion-item` and it didn't work.
I don't know I'm doing wrong. Tried reading Angular documentation but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define correct path to EmailId control.

You have `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s of `FormControl`s but have defined `FormArray` of `FormControl`s in template.

To fix it you should be using `formGroupName` directive.

```
<ion-col ... *ngFor="let email of emails; let i = index">
                                             ||
                                             \/
                                         add this
    <ion-item [formGroupName]="i">
                         ||
                         \/
                       and this
```

Comment: now i get a different error 
`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'PlanEmails -> 1'`
and
`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'PlanEmails -> 1 -> EmailId'`

Comment: This means that your `FormArray` is not synchronized with `emails` array. They you should have the same count of elements

Comment: tried doing this:  
`const emailsArray = new FormArray([]);
            this.emails.forEach(email => {
                emailsArray.controls.push(this.formBuilder.group({EmailId: []}));
            })
            this.planGroup.addControl('PlanEmails', emailsArray);`  
the error is gone now but the formGroup is not filling when a checkbox is selected

Comment: Try `emailsArray.push` instead of `emailsArray.controls.push`. Also you can fill array using `Array.prototype.map` method

Answer (score 0):

There is few examples for FromGroup. Please follow this URL https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms